# join tables using lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, repository-pattern

im very new in MVC,i have got a very big problem in repository pattern,is there anyone who can help me how can i have join and group by between two tables in repository pattern?here is the code:

```
 public class GenericTestRepository<TEntity> where TEntity:class
{

internal CentralEntities context;
internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;


public GenericTestRepository(LTWCentralEntities context )
{
    this.context = context;
    this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
}


public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
    Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
    string includeProperties = "")
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

    if (filter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(filter);
    }

    foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
        (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        query = query.Include(includeProperty);
    }

    if (orderBy != null)
    {
        return orderBy(query).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        return query.ToList();
    }
 }


}
```

Here is my UnitOfWork :

```
   private CentralEntities context = new CentralEntities();
   private GenericRepositoryTest<User> usrRepo;
   private GenericRepositoryTest<MasterData> mastrData;

   public GenericRepositoryTest<User> UserRepo
  {
     get
     {
         return this.usrRepo ?? new GenericRepositoryTest<User>(context);
      }
  }

   public GenericRepositoryTest<MasterData> MastrData
   {
     get
     {
       return this.MastrData ?? new GenericRepositoryTest<MasterData>
 (context);
     }
 }
```

Here in my control i want to join the two tables but i dont know how,if  there was no repository and unit of work pattern i would do the following:

```
 private CentralEntities DB = new CentralEntities();
    var listOfParks = (from s in DB.MasterDatas
                       join t in DB.Users1
                       on s.pv_person_resp_id equals t.user_id                                                           
                       select new SelectListItem
                       {
                           Text = t.user_name
                       }).Distinct().OrderBy(m=>m.Text).ToList();
```

my controller:

```
UnitOfWorkForTest _unitofWork=new UnitOfWorkForTest ();
```

But now i have repository and unit of work,how should i do the join with lambda expression and use my repository and unitofwork?thanks

Comment: What language is this?  Java?  C#?  You need to tag your question with the language you're using.

Comment: @jwodder c-sharp

Comment: In order to help, we need to see the entire method that you tried, not just the method name and parameters. Also, what you are trying to do is in no way related to or dependent on MVC, so it is of no help to mention it (on the contrary).

Comment: @PeterB ok im editing my question

Comment: @PeterB i have edited my question

Comment: Can you show your class and constructor. Where you trying to use this queury?

Comment: @aakash im using it in my controller,this is where i am stucked

Comment: Can you post your controller constructor? and in UnitOfWork Class are you inheriting from the IUnitOfWork class?

Comment: @aakash i updated my question

Comment: did you try by replacing DB with _unitofWork of object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `UnitOfWork` change to

```
public GenericRepositoryTest<MasterData> MastrData
{
   get
    {
      return this.mastrData ?? new GenericRepositoryTest<MasterData>(context);
    }
}
```

Add the following method on your `GenericRepositoryTest` class

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
{
    return _dbSet;
}
```

And finally on your controller:

```
UnitOfWorkForTest _unitofWork=new UnitOfWorkForTest ();

 var listOfParks = (from s in _unitofWork.MastrData.GetAll()
                   join t in _unitofWork.UserRepo.GetAll()
                   on s.pv_person_resp_id equals t.user_id                                                           
                   select new SelectListItem
                   {
                       Text = t.user_name
                   }).Distinct().OrderBy(m=>m.Text).ToList();
```

I hope this helps for you!

Comment: Instead of IList use iqueryable